# Generics Inheriting Multiple Interfaces

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am trying to create a list of type T, where T implements 2 interfaces. To add to this list I have to do a cast, but I feel like I shouldn't have to. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

(`generalLabLookup` returns a `List<Lab>`, `generalVisitLookup` returns a `List<Visit>`. Both `Lab` and `Visit` implement HasId & HasDate, and neither has a superclass other than Object. Neither of the lookup methods, nor the codeCheckDao are generic.)

```
<T extends HasId & HasDate> void labAndVisitAction(int measureYear) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(measureYear, 1, 1);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(measureYear, 12, 31);
    List<T> labsAndVisits = new ArrayList<T>();

    labsAndVisits.addAll( (List<T>) codeCheckDao.generalLabLookup(startDate, endDate, excludeSupp));
    labsAndVisits.addAll((List<T>)codeCheckDao.generalVisitLookup(startDate, endDate, excludeSupp));

    //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the definitions of `generalLabLookup` and `generalVisitLookup`, I don't see a way to answer this question.

Comment: I tell the return types in the comments

Comment: How are `Lab` and `Visit` defined?  Other than that they both implement the two interfaces, are they themselves interfaces?  Are they abstract?  Does one of `Lab` and `Visit` extend the other?  Do they both extend some common class?

Comment: That wasn't the question but how the method's signature looks like. If its return type is only declared as List, the compiler doesn't know about the fact that it's actually List<Lab> and complains

Comment: Lets say that `labAndVisitAction` method accepts `List<T> list` as argument. And you passed there `List<Lab>`. Should compiler automatically allow you to call `list.addAll(codeCheckDao.generalVisitLookup(startDate, endDate, excludeSupp))`? Compiler can't assume what exactly `T` will be at runtime. It can be any type which fulfills `extends HasId & HasDate` condition.

Comment: I see that you edited your post, but my question is still not answered: What are the signatures of the called methods? It doesn't matter what it actually returns during runtime, the declaration matters and if that isn't providing the information the compiler needs, you get errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not enough information about `Lab` and `Visit`, but I'm going to assume that these are concrete types that are unrelated except that they both implement `HasId` and `HasDate`:

```
class Lab implements HasId, HasDate { ... }
class Visit implements HasId, HasDate { ... }
```

Given this, you appear to be trying to create a heterogeneous list that can include both `Lab` and `Visit` objects.  But you can't do this with a concrete type, other than `Object`, because for any concrete type `Concrete`, a `List<Concrete>` *cannot* contain both `Lab` and `Visit` objects.  Based on this, I think it's an error to make this method generic with parameter `<T extends HasId & HasDate>`, since no class type `T` will work.

What you probably want to do is create a `List<InterfaceType>` for some interface type.  That's the normal way to do things when you want a heterogeneous list where all the objects are expected to implement `InterfaceType`, but don't need to have anything else in common.  Your problem is that you have two interface types, and you want the objects in your list to implement both.

The solution is to define a new interface, instead of making it generic:

```
interface HasIdAndDate extends HasId, HasDate {
}
```

and make `labsAndVisits` a `List<HasIdAndDate>` instead of `List<T>`.  (You could run into problems if `HasId` and `HasDate` define methods with the same name and same parameter types, in which case the best solution is probably to change one of the method names.)

**Note:** I have not tested this.

Comment: (You're assumptions are correct btw) Well dern. I was hoping that wasn't needed, but I understand the solution. Thanks